# Libquantum code Understanding Makefile

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, clang

I tried to run .c file called grover.c in this C application libquantum

www.libquantum.de/files/libquantum-1.1.1.tar.gz

Now I this application already contains a Makefile.in and I can generate the executables called shor and grover using the command

```
./configure 
make
make demos
```

But when I try to run grover.c using gcc or clan like this

clang grover.c

It gives me error of lots of undefined function reference.

In function `oracle':
grover.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to`quantum_sigma_x'
grover.c:(.text+0x89): undefined reference to `quantum_toffoli'
grover.c:(.text+0xc8): undefined reference to`quantum_toffoli'
grover.c:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to `quantum_cnot'
grover.c:(.text+0x137): undefined reference to`quantum_toffoli'
grover.c:(.text+0x16b): undefined reference to `quantum_toffoli'
grover.c:(.text+0x1b0): undefined reference to`quantum_sigma_x'

I need to know how can I remove this error and if I can run this c code called grover.c in this application.

Thanks,

Comment: I think you misunderstand what compilers do. To run grover, just type `grover`, there's no need to invoke clang.

Comment: But when I need to compile a single C code I do something like clang hello.c or gcc hello.c and it creates an executable. In this case I need to run this grover.c file. Actually, I want to run this file in another software to profile it for processor usage.

Comment: If you look at the makefile, you'll probably see a lot of stuff in there. If you look at `clang grover.c`, you will likely see a lack of a lot of stuff. This is why it's not working for you. You can't just strip out a single source file from a large project and expect to be able to turn it into an executable. The very fact it comes in that library's project suggests pretty strongly that it's going to use some of the functionality in that library, which you are withholding from it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your compiler can not find one or more libraries to link to.  My hunch is that the `makefile` has the appropriate commands to invoke the linker.

If you look at your makefile, you probably will see some commands like -L -l,
when the flag `-L` add a directory to the default search path for libraries and the flag `-l` is used to name the library to link.

for example `-L/lib/openGL -lglut32` would cause the library libglut32.so.X.Y.Z which is found in the directory /lib/openGL.  (not this is for a Linux system, but it should be fairly similar for Mac).

N.B. X.Y.Z are the version number of the library.

Once you work this out, there may be issues with the load finding the libraries, especially if they are in non-standard locations.

------------------------ edit --------------------------

After I posted this, and went to bed I realized that I missed a potential case (and thanks to Paul Griffiths for also noticing my omission.....teach me to do multiple things at once).

Any how, just compiling a simple file, say hello.c, as clang hello.c -o hello works because everything is in one file and clang will automatically link to the C run-time library.

If, in your case the code is spread across multiple files, say grover.c and file1.c you would need to do:

```
clang -c grover.c -o grover.o
clang -c file1.c -o file1.o
clang grover.o file1.o -o grover
```

(or alteratively clang grover.c file1.c -o grover)

SO what the first two lines are doing is translating the source-code files (grover.c and file1.c) into object files.  THe third line covers the two object files into an executable.

Finally, both these cases can be involved.  You could have multiple files as well as missing libraries.

Comment: It's also eminently possible that `grover.c` is merely one of a number of source files that make up the application `grover`, and that merely linking the library will not be enough.

Comment: Can I use this information in the make file 

grover: libquantum.la grover.c Makefile
 $(LIBTOOL) --mode=link $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o grover grover.c -I./ \
 -lquantum -static -lm


to give appropriate command to the GCC to generate the executable ?

Comment: @jav321 yes.  A makefile is nothing more (slight simplification) then a script that drives GCC.  What you would need to do is determine what the variables CC and CFLAGS contain.  Historically, the variable CC contains the compiler name (in your case I'm guessing it probably is gcc), and CFLAGS contains flags and options that are passed to the compiler.  The rest of the line `-I./ -lquantum -static -lm` would be used as is (I think the \ in your comment is a line-continuation character in the makefile).  If you have any other questions, just ask.